# How to use set of elements as key in java maps?

Tags: java

I want to store a value based on a key, composed of set of elements. Something like the example below. Of course I know that my pseudo-example wouldn't work, as the hash of the object will probably be it's address which will be unique for each new instance, regardless of it's contents.

```
    // in this pseudo-example this is my SET http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/35applications/SET.java.html
    // but the idea is that values are unique
    HashMap<SET<Integer>, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    SET a = new SET();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(5);

    SET b = new SET();
    b.add(5);
    b.add(1);
    b.add(2);

    map.put(a, "w00t");

    System.out.println(map.get(b)); // I would want to get "w00t" because my key is the same set of elements
```

Of course I can just sort and concatenate the SET values as a string, with a separator and use that in a `HashMap<String, String>` structure but that just doesn't feel right. I'm quite new to Java programming so there might be an obvious solution that I'm missing.

Comment: You have to look into `keySet()`. Also it's a `Set` and not `SET`

Comment: I think there is a big problem here if you want to use collections for this job. They are all mutable. What if you add sets (2,3) and (1,2,3), but then you decide to remove a {1} from the second set? Better create a separate immutable object for this, otherwise it will be troubling.

Comment: I realise this, but in my case I won't modify the objects once I store them. Ideally I would like to have an immutable object that I initialise from other iterable, but there isn't one that I can find :(

Comment: because all the collections are mutable. I just think that if you choose this solution it will be a poor design, and it will be vulnerable to errors.

Comment: @pnadczuk For peace of mind, the code could be factored out to its own method to create a set and package it up with [Collections.unmodifiableSet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-) all in one go, so the mutable backing set is never leaked anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `HashSet<Integer>` instead of your custom SET (I'm assuming it's a custom class), it would work just fine, since `HashSet` overrides `hashCode` and `equals` (to be exact, `HashSet` extends `AbstractSet` which overrides these methods), so it can serve as a key in a `HashMap`.

However, if you modify a Set that serves as a key in your Map, you wouldn't be able to locate that key in the Map later. That's the risk you run into when using mutable objects as keys in a HashMap.

```
HashMap<HashSet<Integer>, String> map = new HashMap<HashSet<Integer>, String>();
HashSet<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(5);

HashSet<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>();
b.add(5);
b.add(1);
b.add(2);

map.put(a, "w00t");

System.out.println(map.get(b));
```

This outputs `w00t`.

Comment: I looked into it. It doesn't override, it just inherits.

Comment: @ddinchev It works fine. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @ddinchev Yes, I was inaccurate, AbstractSet does the overriding.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This seems like the obvious and best solution to me.

Comment: I can confirm this is actually working just as described! Just upvoted it and all comments, thank you @Eran! In few minutes I'll accept the anser. Is there a way to make an immutable HashSet from another collection, or I'd have to extend HashSet, make a constructor that creates the set from iterable values and override the methods that attempt to mutate the object?

Comment: and what if you add two different sets, but then you alter them and they are suddenly equal?? you can't grant their immutability

Comment: @pnadczuk I did mention that using any mutable class as key in a HashMap is problematic. You would be in trouble even if they are not equal after the change, since their hashCodes would change.

Comment: [Collections.unmodifiableSet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-)

Comment: @up Agree, that's a good idea. Either that one or ImmutableSet or it's subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Create a collection class and override hashcode() in a way where the same hashcode is returned for different collection instances with the same content. You can simply override the method in a class deriving from your desired collection. You do have to reimplement equals(Object o) as well.

Comment: How about two OrderedSet instances with a different Comparator?

Comment: Still works. If you check the docs for [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), you can see that it inherits its [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#hashCode--) implementations from `AbstractSet`. "The Set interface places additional stipulations, beyond those inherited from the Collection interface, on the contracts of all constructors and on the contracts of the add, equals and hashCode methods."

Answer (score -1):

It depends on you of SET class implementation. You can either extend `java.util.HashSet` class or implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your SET class. Any solution will work.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't add set `b` to your map. First add both sets and then try to get value associated with the key `b`.

Comment: That's the OP's point - both sets have the same elements and should be identical, but an object added with `a` as the key can't be retrieved using `b`. This happens because he didn't override `hashCode` or `equals` in his custom set implementation.